# Promise.all iterable argument

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to use `Promise.all` to run a few requests asynchronously but I will be getting an object where the keys are important.  I have passed arrays in to `Promise.all` but can I pass an object where the value of each property is a promise? Will I be able to access the results in the then callback by key?
I looked at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and they say to pass in iterable but only show examples of arrays being passed in.

Comment: Click on the link to the `Iterable` documentation on the web page you linked to. It says: _Some built-in types, such as Array or Map, have a default iteration behavior, while other types (such as Object) do not._

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from adding the Iterable protocol to an object that you define, though. It's just not implemented by default. You could also use a `Map` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I just whipped up

```
Promise.allObject = function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var promises = keys.map(function(key) { return obj[key]; });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
        return data.reduce(function(result, val, indx) {
            result[keys[indx]] = val;
            return result;
        }, {});
    });
};
```

Here's a test, which worked for me

```
var dummy = function(v) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), (Math.random() * 2000 + 2000) >>> 0);
    });
};

Promise.allObject({
    key1: dummy('a'),
    key2: dummy('c'),
    key3: dummy('b'),
    key4: 'not a promise'
})
.then(console.log.bind(console))
.catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

after about 4 seconds (the dummy function has a random timeout) it output

`Object { key1: "a", key2: "c", key3: "b", key4: "not a promise" }`

Useful?

Comment: What do you _think_ is wrong with the way it handles rejections?

Comment: native `Promise.all` does too - that's what I was aiming for, to mimic Promise.all behaviour with an Object